# Print ancestors of all nodes in a Binary Tree. Can we do it in less than O(n^2) time complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

This is the standard algorithm for printing ancestors of a **particular** Node in a Binary Tree and it takes O(n) time complexity.

```
bool print(Node *node,int target){
    if(node==NULL)
       return false;
    if(node->target==target)
       return true;
    if(print(node->left)||print(node->right)){
       cout << node->data;
       return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

The question is if we need to print all ancestors of **all node's** and also store ancestors in an array for each node. what is the time complexity? Can we do it better than O(n^2) i.e without looping through each node and find ancestors.If possible how?

Comment: Underspecified. In what order? If a node is an ancestor of multiple nodes does it have to be printed multiple times? And you seem to not be assuming the tree is balanced.

Comment: That's a pretty weird algorithm - it would be much easier with a pointer from child to parent.

Comment: The time it takes to do this is just proportional to the size of the output.  For balanced trees that's O(N log N).  For unbalanced trees it's O(N^2)

Comment: @PeterG. I want all ancestors of each node to be in array separately.Each node should have its own array.

Comment: @Alan Stokes Order may be from child to parent or parent to child.

Comment: Does the tree have pointers to the parents?

Comment: No parent pointers.But I need do both with and without parent pointers.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in `O(n*h)`, where `h` is the tree's height, by implementing a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), that keeps track of currently open nodes.

A simple c++ like pseudo code can be something like:

```
void PrintAll(const Node& node) {
  open = std::unordered_set<Node>;  // empty hash set
  PrintAll(node, &open);
}
void PrintAll(const Node& node, std::unordered_set* open) {
  if (node == null) 
     return;
  for (const Node& ancestor: open)
     cout << ancestor<< "," << node;
  open->add(node);
  PrintAll(node.left, open);
  PrintAll(node.right, open);
  open->remove(node);
}
```

Caveat: In here, we do not print `(node, node)` (each node is also an ancestor of itself). If we want to do it, it can be fixed easily by adding the addition of `node` to `open` before the printing loop.

Also, you can make the `unordered_set` store only the data, rather than the entire node.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an *array* corresponding to each node in the tree, then you cannot do better than O(N<sup>2</sup>) worst case, because the total size of all arrays is worst case O(N<sup>2</sup>) (in the case that every node in the tree has at most one child). If you expect the trees to be somewhat balanced, this reduces to O(N log N).

You can achieve O(N) construction by sharing data, using a linked list instead of an array for each node. In effect, that's equivalent to computing a parent link for each node, because the linked list is simply a traversal of parent links. But you cannot avoid the cost of printing, because you will print average O(N log N) / worst case O(N<sup>2</sup>) items when you print out all the ancestor chains.

The parent link construction algorithm is basically the same as the algorithm you present: recursively walk the tree setting the parent links of the children to the current node. To print the ancestor chains for each node, you can use the parent links while you walk the tree.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the job :

Language Used : Java

```
//  Algorithm for printing the ancestors of a Node.
static boolean findAncestors(Node root, Node a)
{
    if(root==null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(root==a)
    {
        System.out.print("Printing ancestors of node " + a.data + " : " + a.data);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        boolean var=false;
        var=findAncestors(root.left, a);
        if(var)
        {
            System.out.print(", " + root.data);
            return true;
        }

        var=findAncestors(root.right, a);
        if(var)
        {
            System.out.print(", " + root.data);
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```